# Letter Text One By One In Correct Location

Tags: animation-nodes

I'm able to have text appear using [image]

[image]

I'd like to get letters in the right place one at a time, any ideas?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not intelligent but brutal approach: track furthest vertex (max X coordinate) from full length text and use it as location offset.

**Text** (solid shade) - object with single letter

**Text.001** (orange wire) - full length text for tracking purpose

[image]

Unfortunately, execution will get slower on every next letter due to mesh converting and sorting.

Comment: Love the Scarface reference...

Answer (score 2):

We can do this using a simple python expression. The idea here is to replace every character with single space except for the character in given index.

`''.join(map(str, [ch if i==y else " " for i,ch in enumerate(x)]))`

[image]

[image]

Another method using `Decompose Text` node:

[image]